# AES GCM decryption security

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes, google-cloud-messaging

When I decrypt using AES GCM, if my Authentication Tag does not match the computed Authentication Tag (indicating something supplied in the decryption process is incorrect), is it completely safe for the user to see the output from the decryption?

Or should I set the output from the decryption to zeroes so that the potential attacker can not get any information back besides the decryption process failing?

I am worried that some hacker/mathematician would be able to begin guessing the key value more accurately if they had access to the output from the decryption.

Answer (score 1):

The key value will be safe what ever you do - bar side channel attacks or abusing the key bytes. A block cipher such as AES is designed not to give any information back about the key. If the GCM authentication fails then you should not make the decrypted data available. Failure is failure - if GCM fails you cannot trust the contents of the bytes.

If you want to thwart attack, make sure that the attacker cannot easily change the plaintext that is encrypted, and make sure that *all the bytes of the authentication tag are always verified*. With GCM it also pays to make the authentication tag as big as possible.

Returning a minimum amount of information is generally seen as a good defense as well. Zapping the encrypted bytes to zero is probably a good thing, as long as you don't return any of those bytes.

Comment: Ok.  I raised a red flag at work when I saw that they were proposing to return the bytes even when there was an Authentication Tag failure.  I don't have an in depth knowledge of cryptography and was worried how exposed it was or if it was GCM protocol not to return the bytes.

Comment: It won't expose the key, but the data will only be interesting for debugging purposes. Sometimes you get e.g. half the ciphertext, that could mean some kind of connection problems (or, in my case, people that keep insisting that FTP is a good protocol and yes, they can detect if a file has been fully received and written). But basically you should stop processing the ciphertext otherwise. It can contain literally anything.